# How to scale meteor app on Heroku using cluster package?

Tags: heroku, meteor, meteor-packages

Friends,
Is there a way to scale meteor app hosted on heroku using cluster package by Arunoda? BTW heroku now supports sticky session aka session affinity (heroku labs:enable http-session-affinity) although its stsill experimental.
I tried to follow Arunoda's guide from link https://meteorhacks.com/cluster-a-different-kind-of-load-balancer-for-meteor, but every time it ended up in my ROOT_URL server and never distributed to my secondary host.
Below is the settings I have on heroku.
Main host
[image]
Secondary host
[image]

Now my questions are:
1. Is it possible to achieve loadbalancing on heroku using cluster package?
2. If yes, then is my configuration below correct?
3. How can I test/verify that loadbalancing is working?
4. If no, what are other options available for loadbalancing on heroku?